# How to request a JSON with ajax on AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, json, ajax, django, angularjs-http

How request a JSON with ajax on AngularJS?
I have written my site on django.
On get request to 0.0.0.0:8000/json/ ,it sends back a json.object

At django, part  views.py:

```
def send_json(request, param):
        result_dict = dict()
        result_dict['hello'] = 'world'
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(result_dict, ensure_ascii=False), content_type="application/json; encoding=utf-8")
```

When I visit 0.0.0.0:8000/json/ in browser, I see json.

On Angular, I have read this article - fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js//consuming-external-services/requesting-json-data-with-ajax.html and implemented my code

```
(function(){
    angular.module('myapp',[])

    //define controller and inject $http service as dependency.
    .controller('ajax',['$http','$scope',function($http,$scope){ 
        $http.get('0.0.0.0:8000/json/').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.posts = data;
                }).
                    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                });
    }])        
})();
```

GET request in Django is working but nothing is being displayed. When I change link at angular to fetch a local json it's working perfectly.

What is the mistake I am making?

Comment: 0.0.0.0 isn't an address you can request; it's just the address you can tell your server to listen on as it means "bind to all IPs". You should use "localhost" or "127.0.0.1".

Comment: "localhost" or "127.0.0.1" doesn't help. AngularJS  catch error (I append alert(1) at error and see it :) )

Comment: @Nuvemap is yout call going though. Can you put a console.log($scope.posts) when the $http call is being successful and check if the http is successful is getting the data.

Comment: Do you mind telling us what the error is, then?

Comment: It was Access-Control-Allow-Origin error :( I fix it.